# How to use any Object and pass it into a Generic SwiftUI View?

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, functional-programming, protocols

**Context**

I have a `Protocol` called `Component` and a `Computed Variable`, that returns a specific `Object` conforming to `Component` as `any Component`.
I also have a `Generic SwiftUI View` accepting a `Component`.

> **Compiler Error:** Type 'any Component' cannot conform to 'Component'

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Component: ObservableObject { var name: String }

struct ComponentView<C: Component>: View {
    @ObservedObject var component: C

    var body: some View { Text(c.name) }
}

struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ComponentView(component: component) // Compiler Error
    }

    private var component: any Component { // Returns any Component }
}
```

---

**Question**

- I understand that `any Component` and `Component` are two different `Types`. However, I am looking for a possibility to use the given `Component` in the `ComponentView`. How can I achieve this goal of using the returned `Component` inside `ComponentView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var component: any Component` declaration means that the property can virtually hold any value that conforms to the protocol, meaning the exact type of the value stored there is to be determined at runtime.

On the other hand, `ComponentView<C: Component>` is a compile-time construct, and the compiler needs to know which type will fill in the blanks, something that is not possible due to the `any` construct.

You'll have to either

- propagate `any` downstream - from `RootView` to `ComponentView`, and remove the generic on `ComponentView`, or
- propagate the generic requirement upstream - from `ComponentView` to `RootView`, and make `RootView` generic.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However, I was watching the `WWDC22` video on this topic and they said something about being able to turn `any Object` into `some Object`, which then could be used with a `Generic SwiftUI View`. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: @christophriepe at some point every `any` gets unboxed into a `some`, however, those are still runtime constructs, and I don't think they work well with generics, which are compile-time constructs. I might be wrong regarding the latter, though,